# Why can't I define an "or-function" in scheme?

Tags: scheme

I have found this question about the special function "or" in scheme:

> Joe Hacker states loudly that there is no reason or in Scheme needs to be special -- it can just be defined by the programmer, like this:
>
> ```
> (define (or x y)
>     (if x
>         #t
>         y))
> ```
>
> Is Joe right?

I can't figure out why it shouldn't be possible to do that.

Could some scheme-expert please explain if this works, and if no: why not?

Comment: I don't know what book you're using to learn Scheme, so I had to go to [the Scheme language specification](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.4.5). "If there are no <test>s, #f is returned. Otherwise, the <test> expressions are evaluated from left to right until a <test> returns a true value val (see section 5.7) or the last <test> is reached. In the former case, the or expression returns val without evaluating the remaining expressions. In the latter case, the last expression is evaluated and its values are returned." Does Joe's `or` function work this way?

Comment: http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse341/99wi/scheme/mini-exercises.html

Comment: By the way, it *can* be defined by the programmer, but not as a simple function. It's not special for certain values of special. http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/further.html#defn:or

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because this version of `or` evaluates all of its arguments (since it's a function), while the standard Scheme `or` (which is not a function but special syntax) doesn't. Try running `(or #t (exit))` at the Scheme REPL and then try the same with your `or` function.

The behavior of the standard `or` is sometimes called [short-circuited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation): it evaluates only those arguments that it needs to. This is very common for the binary boolean operator (`or` and `and`) across programming languages. The fact that `or` *looks like* a function call is a feature of Scheme/Lisp syntax, but looks deceive.

Comment: That's it! Thank you for your explaination, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Whether it works or not depends on what you want it to do. It certainly works in the sense that for two given boolean values it will return the expected resulted. However it will not be functionally equivalent to regular `or` because it does not short-circuit, i.e. given your definition `(or #t (/ 0 0))` will cause an error because you're dividing 0 by 0 while using regular `or` it would just return `#t` and not try to evaluate `(/ 0 0)` at all.